# How can I reference an object from a child of a movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3

I feel like this question is fairly simple, but I am not too familiar with as3 yet.

So I added a menu on the stage:

```
var umenu:upgradeMenu = new upgradeMenu(dayNum,damageModifier,speedModifier);
umenu.x=stage.stageWidth/2;
umenu.y=stage.stageHeight/2;
umenu.visible=false;
addChild(umenu)
```

Now, I have a transition animation added right after this and when the time is right I want to be able to reference "umenu" to change it's visibility to true.
The code will be called on a frame in the transitions animation but I can't figure out how to reference umenu?

```
MovieClip(root).umenu.visible=true;
```

^^ I know that wont work because its not a movieclip technically so how would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!
I didn't think about giving it a name then accessing it as a child from root.

```
MovieClip(root).getChildByName("upgradem")
```

"upgradem" is the name I gave umenu.
I'd still like to hear if there is a better solution however